# How can we add 3% of amount to each account

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to add 3% of total amount to each account

Is there any mysql query that would calculate 3% of amount for each account and add the amount to that account

Can I use a dynamic variable ?

Any suggestions!

Comment: Yes of course **you** can write a query like that

Comment: But as you have not even given us the most basic of real information it will have to be **you** that writes it

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to multiply the value with 1.03 this you can do within an update statement like:

```
UPDATE Account
SET Value=Value*1.03
```

Cheers!
Niek

Answer (score 1):

you could do this

```
SET column1 = (column1+((column1*3)/100))
```

or this

```
SET column1 = column1 * 1.03
```